# Max retries exceeded with url... (Caused by SSLError) certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, ssl

I am using python Selemium,
this is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chrome_options = Options() 
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
chrome_options.add_argument('ignore-certificate-errors')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(),options=chrome_options)
```

and this is my error message: 
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /LATEST_RELEASE_96.0.4664 (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1091)')))

I tried: pip install --upgrade certifi, 
 it didn't help.